# How do I add a pipe seperator between words using this printf statement?

Tags: php, printf

Im displaying a list of categories using this printf statement:

`printf( __( ' %4$s', 'bonestheme' ), get_the_time( 'Y-m-j' ), get_the_time( __( 'F jS, Y', 'bonestheme' )), bones_get_the_author_posts_link(), get_the_term_list( get_the_ID(), 'custom_cat', "" ) );`

which outputs this:

[image: categories with no space or separator]

I only want to add a little space and a pipe separator between the words (the custom categories) to output this:

[image: categories with pipe separator]

I've played around trying to get this to work with no success. I know there's a simple solution for this but I am not familiar with the printf statement.

Any help would be appreciated so much. Thanks.

Comment: How does "get_the_time" produce a city name?

Comment: the parameter 'custom_cat' is what's being displayed. In my blog I have custom categories setup so I can add the cities I need to reference.

Answer (score 2):

After a little more research on the printf statement I realized there were some additional parameters missing.

I was able to accomplish this with the following code:

`printf( __( ' %4$s', 'bonestheme' ), get_the_time( 'Y-m-j' ), get_the_time( __( 'F jS, Y', 'bonestheme' )), bones_get_the_author_posts_link(), get_the_term_list( get_the_ID(), 'custom_cat', ' ', ' | ', '' ) );`

as you can see in the new code I have added the pipe separator wrapped by single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following for the pipe("|") character:

```
&#124
```

Comment: I noticed the code I was previously using was missing some additional parameters. Once I added them using the pipe separator in the second  of the three added parameters it worked. Would it better to use the code for the pipe &#124 rather than just entering the pipe by keyboard?